# Collect AJAX results in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an array of values (`myarray`), that I want to iterate through and run an AJAX request on each iteration.  I've put each ajax request inside another array (`requests`), so that I can call an `alert` when all AJAX requests have completed:

Like so:

```
var requests = [];
for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; ++i) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
        url: 'anotherurl?=' + myarray[i],
        dataType: "JSONP",
        success: function (data) {
          array_of_results.push(data);
        }
    }));
}
$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    alert('complete');
});
```

All the results are collected in `array_of_results`.  However due to the AJAX requests taking different lengths of time to complete, this array doesn't have the results in the original order.

Is there any way to order this array?

I hope I've made sense.  I appreciate this is quite convoluted.

Comment: ajax call in a for loop . Is it necessary ?

Comment: It's best to do this job by utilizing Promises. Such as mapping your array into a promises array (say `myPromiseArray`) and then invoking `Promise.all(myPromiseArray).then(onFulFillment, onReject)` Where the `onFulfillment` and `onReject` callbacks will be provided with an array of results coming from the promises in the original order.

Comment: Asi understand the $.ajax() call returns an jqXHR object which since V1.5 harbors all properties, methods and behavior of Promise interface. So implementing what i have mentioned in the above comment should be a bliss. For more on that http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the following? I think this should work.  All the responses should be available, in order, in the success function of the `when()`.

```
var requests = [];
for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; ++i) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
        url: 'anotherurl?=' + myarray[i],
        dataType: "JSONP"
    }));
}
$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    array_of_results = arguments;
    alert('complete');
});
```

Comment: it miss pushing data into array_of_results when success (of each ajax call)

Comment: I have corrected my example. You need to use the special JS keyword "arguments" to get the success function parameters in the form of an array.

Comment: Ok.. but the order will be yet that of returned ajax call not that of the calling

Comment: No. It should be in the same order as you added the calls to the `requests` array

Comment: ok, I miss that "when.apply" waits for all requests are resolved and then call "done" function..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a loop consider using recursion. Here's a complete example:

```
var myArray = [
    "somevalue",
    "some other value",
    "another value"
];
var i = myArray.length;
var responses = [];

function doRequests(){
    i--;
    $.ajax({
        url: "myurl.php",
        data: {paramname: myArray[i]}
    }).done(function(response){
        responses.push(response);
        if(i>0) doRequests();
        else{
            // all requests sent.. do stuff
            // responses array is in order
            console.log(responses);
            alert("all done!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom attribute to your `$.ajax` object, setted to your `i` var.

```
var requests = [];
for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; ++i) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
        url: 'anotherurl?=' + myarray[i],
        dataType: "JSONP",
        myCustomIndex: i,
        success: function (data) {
          array_of_results[this.myCustomIndex] = data;
        }
    }));
}
$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    alert('complete');
});
```

JavaScript is really permisive, if you attribute a value to an array out of its bounds (higher than 0), the size of the array will be automaticaly set to the right amount.

Comment: I think that "i" value is always the last value of "for" cycle (see closure...)

Answer (score -1):

How about using jquery.ajax call with async setting as false. This way the reaponse will be in order as requested...

Comment: It will hang up browsers and stops other process :)

Comment: also, i'm pretty sure it's deprecated. i feel like i saw a message in the console to that effect last time i tried sjax..

Answer (score -1):

Building on @Christo's answer - using arrays map function

```
var array_of_results = [];
var requests = myarray.map(function(item, index) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'anotherurl?=' + item,
        dataType: "JSONP",
        success: function (data) {
            array_of_results[index] = data;
        }
    }
});
```

...

Comment: why the downvote? it's perfectly good code, just because Christo deleted his answer doesn't make this answer less valid - anonymous cowards downvote without explanation